# File Upload issue

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, web-config, devexpress

I have problem with uploading files larger than 6-7 mb with DevExpress aspxFileUpload control when I change debug from true to false in my web.config compilation section.

I also set `maxRequestLength="51200"` in httpRuntime section.

Comment: Also try setting the execution timeout (it doesn't apply in debug mode) -  `executionTimeout="90"` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following solutions to see if it corrects your problem:

Method 1:

Increase the connection time-out setting
To increase the connection time-out setting, follow these steps.

Note By default, the IIS connection time-out setting is 120 seconds.

1.Click Start, point to All Programs, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
2.Right-click the virtual server that you want to configure, and then click Properties.
3.Click the Web Site tab. 
4.Under Connections, type the number of seconds that you want in the Connection time-out box, and then click OK.

Method 2:

Add the executionTimeout value
1.Open the Web.config file in Notepad.

2.Add the executionTimeout value that you want. For example, replace the value as follows.

```
<location path="upload.aspx"> 
    <system.web> 
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="999999" maxRequestLength="2097151" /> 
    </system.web> 
  </location>
```

Comment: many thanks  Pabloker and tam tam. increasing executionTimeout solved the problem... thanks again...

Comment: @Behnam Gald too see that your issue is resolved :-)  Would you kindly mark the answer as correct?